# Android bitmap creation by View.getDrawingCache() on SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

It appears that you can create a bitmap from what is showing on the screen via View.getDrawingCache() once View.setDrawingCacheEnabled() is set to true.  But it does not seems to work for the SurfaceView(It returns black where the surface view is placed). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-platform/xHIActZZ9PA

> Sorry, by its nature a SurfaceView does not draw in the normal view hierarchy update system, so it won't be drawn in that.